# JxBrowser Chrome Memory leak when refresh browser by useing Calling Java from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jxbrowser

I did a simple demo when useing JxBrowser Calling Java from JavaScript, and then I found the phenomenon,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches("--remote-debugging-port=9222");

  Browser browser1 = new Browser();
  BrowserView browserView1 = new BrowserView(browser1);

  // Gets URL of the remote Developer Tools web page for browser1 instance.
  String remoteDebuggingURL = browser1.getRemoteDebuggingURL();

  browser1.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
      Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
      JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
      window.asObject().setProperty("java", new JavaObject());
    }
  });

  JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
  frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame1.add(browserView1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame1.setSize(700, 500);
  frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  frame1.setVisible(true);

  browser1.loadURL("https://www.baidu.com");

  // Creates another Browser instance and loads the remote Developer
  // Tools URL to access HTML inspector.
  Browser browser2 = new Browser();
  BrowserView browserView2 = new BrowserView(browser2);

  JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
  frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame2.add(browserView2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame2.setSize(700, 500);
  frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  frame2.setVisible(true);

  browser2.loadURL(remoteDebuggingURL);
}
```

I run the code and refresh the chrome, many times and then 
[before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkQV5.png)

[refresh 2 Minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV5IE.png)

if user other network with more resources or images ,The Memory increase more faster, Would like to ask whether this problem can be solved
thanks all!
I'm looking forward to the reply!

Comment: [refresh 5 Minute][1]

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSOTv.png

Answer (score 0):

I checked your example and I confirm that it is an issue in JxBrowser. I've created the corresponding task in our issue tracking system. We will fix this issue in one of the next JxBrowser versions. I will let you know when the new build with the fix is available for download.